# Java Cannot run program CreateProcess error=2

Tags: java, git, shell

i'd like to run a command that executes a shell script with the java class "DefaultExecutor", but i get this error:

```
Cannot run program "get_encrypted_password.sh" (in directory "C:\Temp\scripts"): CreateProcess error=2 specified file not found".
```

the script works well with git bash.

can someone tell me where i'm doing wrong?

```
public Entity updateWithEncryptedPassword(Entity entity) throws IOException {
    String password = entity.getPwd();

    String security_key = "00000000000000000000000000000000";

    String path = "C:/Temp/scripts"; 

    CommandLine commandLine = CommandLine.parse("get_encrypted_password.sh");

    commandLine.addArgument(password);

    commandLine.addArgument(security_key);

    String encrypted_password = Utils.runCommandAndGetOutput(commandLine, path);

    entity.setNewPwd(encrypted_password);

    return super.update(entity);
}

public static String runCommandAndGetOutput(CommandLine commandLine, String path) throws IOException {
    DefaultExecutor defaultExecutor = new DefaultExecutor();
    defaultExecutor.setExitValue(0);
    defaultExecutor.setWorkingDirectory(new File(path));

    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PumpStreamHandler streamHandler = new PumpStreamHandler(outputStream);

    defaultExecutor.setStreamHandler(streamHandler);

    defaultExecutor.execute(commandLine);

    return outputStream.toString();
}
```

Comment: Java won't give Windows the ability to run Unix shell scripts; there is a way to install Unix services in Windows (either Services For Unix or Ubuntu), but the process is part of Windows installation/configuration.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thats interesting. Nice to know for the future...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of executing "get_encrypted_password.sh", which cannot be ran under Windows, execute "bash", (probably git bash,) and pass "get_encrypted_password.sh" as a parameter to it, so that bash will execute your script.

Comment: The strange thing though is that error 2 is "file not found", and I would have expected some different error.  Or perhaps the error is "file not found" because windows was trying to find and execute some "get_encrypted_password.sh.exe" or "get_encrypted_password.sh.bat"

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i'll give it a try. :)